# SOA/Microservices: How to handle authorization in inter-services communications?

Tags: api, microservices, soa, authorization

**Foreground**

We are moving from a monolithic platform to a more Service Oriented Architecture. We are applying very basic DDD principles and splitting our domain across different bounded contexts. Each domain is distributed and exposes a service via a web API (REST).

Due to the nature of our business, we have services such as *Bookings*, *Services*, *Customers*, *Products*, etc.

We have also set up an Identity Server (based on Thinktecture Identity Server 3) whose main role is to:

- Centralize authentication (given credentials it issues tokens)
- Add claims in the tokens such as: the scopes of the client (as per client I mean the application doing the request), customer identifier (as per customer I mean the person using the application)

We also introduced the role of an *API Gateway* which centralizes external access to our services. API Gateway provides functionalities which do not require deep knowledge of the internal domains such as:

- Reverse proxy: routes incoming requests into the appropriate internal service
- Versioning: a version of the API Gateway maps to different versions of the internal services
- Authentication: client requests include the token issued by the Identity Server and the API Gateway validates the token (make sure user is who says she is)
- Throttling: limit number of requests per client

**Authorization**

What concerns authorization, this is not managed in the API Gateway but in the internal services itself. We are currently doing 2 main types of authorizations:

- Authorization based on client scopes. Example: a client (external application consuming our APIs) requires the scope "bookings" to access the *Bookings* service API endpoints
- Authorization based on the customer. Example: only if a customer (physical person using the application) is a participant of a booking can access the endpoint GET /bookings from the *Bookings* service

To be able to handle authorization in the internal services, the API Gateway simply forwards the token (when routing the request to the internal service) which includes both information about the client (the application doing the request) and the customer as a claim (in those cases where a person is logged in the client application).

**Problem description**

So far so good until we introduced inter-service communication (some services can communicate with other services to obtain some data).

**Question**

How should we approach the authorization in inter-services communications?

**Options considered**

To discuss the different options I will use the following sample scenario:

- We have an external application called *ExternalApp* that accesses our API (*ExternalApp* can be seen as *the client*) in order to build the booking flow
- *ExternalApp* needs access to the *Bookings* service, hence we grant the *ExternalApp* the scope "bookings"
- Internally (this is something completely transparent for the *ExternalApp*) the *Bookings* service acesses the *Services* service to obtain the default services of a booking such as the flights, the insurances or a car rental

When discussing this issue internally several options popped up, but we are not sure which option is best:

1. When *Bookings* communicates with *Services*, it should simply forward the original token he received from the API Gateway (indicating that the client is the *ExternalApp*)

   - Implications: We might need to grant scopes to the *ExternalApp* that should not have been granted. Example: *ExternalApp* might need to have both the scope "bookings" and "services" while only the "bookings" scope could have sufficed
2. When *Bookings* communicates with *Services*, it forwards a token indicating the client now has become *Bookings* (instead of the *ExternalApp*) + it adds a claim indicating *Bookings* is impersonating the original client *ExternalApp*

   - By also including the information that the original client is the *ExternalApp* the *Services* service could also do logic such as filtering out some services depending on the original caller (e.g. for internal apps we should return all fights, for external apps only some)
3. Services should not communicate with each other (so we should not be even be facing this question)

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: How did you solve this problem ? We are in a similar situation.

Comment: +1 : I am interested in how you finally solve your problem.

Comment: In order to do point 3 - services do not communicate with each other, you need a composite UI. See https://particular.net/blog/secret-of-better-ui-composition

Answer (score 5):

I advise you to have an **internal** channel of communication between the microservices.

For example, using some **message broker** like RabbitMQ internally to **send/receive** or **publish/subscribe** messages between the microservices.

Then your end-user facing service "in your example the Booking service" will be responsible for validating the token and authorizing the customer to do this specific operation "maybe by communicating with IdentityServer".

Then it will communicate with the "Services" service through the Message broker. In this case, there is no need to validate the token again.

**I guess this model will be simpler and give you a better performance.**